# Do we need to write our own middle-ware, or we can make use of available reporting tool

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, jasper-reports, report

Previously, we have a legacy system, which we are using C++ code to generate reports in Text file and Excel file. However, it is a pain to perform manual coding to perform all the raw data processing and report format rendering.

Recently, we had success to migrate all the raw data into SQL database.

To avoid writing manual code, we decide to evaluate the following tool.

1. [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) - Able to help us perform report format rendering?
2. [OpenReport](http://oreports.com/) - Provides us web access to the generated report?

Currently, our raw data looks something like :
[image]

Based on the demo provided by OpenReport and JasperReports, I believe we can generate a report like

```
Summary Report for Lot 2
------------------------

Measurement     Type        Value
----------------------------------
Lead 1          Average     1.30
Lead 1          StdDev      0.16
.
.
Lead 2          Average     2.08
Lead 2          StdDev      0.55
```

However, this is a little far than what we want. What we want is to able

1. Take the multiple rows of `Lead 1, 2, 3`... under Average category, and have a logic code function to recalculate them into a single `Lead` row.
2. Do the same for rest of the statistics like StdDev...
3. Have a report format like :

---

```
Summary Report for Lot 2
------------------------

Measurement     Average     StdDev
----------------------------------
Lead            2.33        1.23
```

---

So far for the demo that I had seen, most of them are just `1 to 1 mapping` from raw database to report. In the middle of `1 to 1 mapping`, I know there can be some simple SQL statement for filtering and manipulation. I haven't seen an example which can perform a `sophisticated` processing.

The reason I call it `sophisticated`, as in C++ code, we require to perform std::string processing, making use of std::vector, std::map data structure and arithmetic operation. I am doubt SQL statement can perform similar.

Based on my listed **3** requirement, is it possible that I can use available reporting tool in the market to generate report? Or we need to develop our own middle-ware to perform such task? (Perl/ Python/ ... whatever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your database schema is adequet, you should be able to do what in need in SQL and JasperReports.

With PostgreSQL, you can do things like [string manipulation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), grouping, aggregate functions, etc.
With JasperReports, you can manipulate your data with Java, use subreports, etc.

The specific example can be done like this:

- Use this query to get the data, using only the part before the space ('Lead'): `select split_part(measurement_type, ' ', 1), measurement_statistic_type, value`
- Use a PivotTable in JasperReports - it would automatically aggregate the data the way you wanted it.

There are also pure SQL ways to get this done.

Note:

- Make sure you design your database schema to support your reporting needs (for example, instead of spliting `measurenet_type`, why not have two columns - `measurement_name` / `measurement_id`?)
- You can't really aggregate stddev. The average of stddev is not the same as stddev of the entire population.

Comment: For your 1st note, because insertion speed is priority in our requirement. We had make it as 2 columns in our first design, it doesn't meet to our speed. By having this design, it meet.

Comment: I first also thought I cant have aggregate stddev. But in fact, you can. I just spend a day to perform derivation out from here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_formulas_for_the_variance

Comment: extra note, you need to have their average value as well, in order to compute their aggregate variance out from their individual variance.

Comment: Thanks for the stddev aggregate tip, I'll use it. Are you able to use my answer? There are also other ways to do it with SQL+Jasper. If you want to go even further to the next level, you might want to check OLAP products, like mondrian, which is built for pivot-tables, drill-down, etc.